# How to avoid Parallel Inheritance hierarchy in an API/Library

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working on an encryption library to simplify how my team uses encryption for api credentials and receiving encrypted messages from other teams/projects.

I started with these top-level interfaces to define the domain:

```
public interface Key {
    public byte[] getBytes();
}

public interface Message {
    public byte[] getBytes();
}

public interface Secret {
    public byte[] getBytes();
}

public interface Decrypter {
    public String decrypt(Secret secret, Key key);
}

public interface Encrypter {
    public Secret encrypt(Message message, Key key);
}
```

This worked well to wrap RSA encryption:

```
public class KeyPair {
    private final Key publicKey;
    private final Key privateKey;

    public Key getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public Key getPrivateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }
}

public class RsaEncrypter implements Encrypter {

    @Override
    public Secret encrypt(Message message, Key publicKey) {
        // Perform Encryption
    }
}

public class RsaDecrypter implements Decrypter {
    @Override
    public String decrypt(Secret secret, Key privateKey) {
        // Perform the decryption
    }
}
```

But now that I'm applying it to our AES Encryption use cases I've encountered a problem. The Secret contains an InitializationVector because we're using AES in CBC mode.

So I've got this:

```
public class AesSecret implements Secret {
    private byte[] cipherText;
    private byte[] initilizationVector;

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return cipherText;
    }

    public byte[] getInitilizationVector() {
        return initilizationVector;
    }
}

public class AesDecrypter implements Decrypter {
    @Override
    public String decrypt(Secret secret, Key key) {
        try {
            return decrypt((AesSecret) secret, key);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("AesDecrypter only supports subclasses of AesSecret", e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(AesSecret secret, Key key) {
        // Do the AES Decryption
    }
}
```

The ClassCastException makes me think that I'm violating the Liskov Substitution Principle, and introducing the parallel hierarchy code-smell. I've read the Visitor pattern is a common solution to this code smell, but I haven't figured out how it would apply to my situation.

Any suggestions? Or am I over-thinking this?

I've added these classes to a Gist: https://gist.github.com/mmeier/c493c28cbcd57a73d08419066cd23484

Comment: Generics. Make the `en/decrypter` generic in the `Secret`. Create and `interface` - `CbcSecret` that `extends Secret` and adds the IV.

Comment: Also, all the interfaces with `getBytes` would seem to be begging for some parent. And `public` methods on interfaces make me sad.

Comment: Finally is seems strange that `Decrypter` takes a `Message` and `Encrypter` returns a `String`. I would expect them to be inverses of eachother.

Comment: I'd seriously suggest not rolling your own encryption API.  Why not just use java.security, or some other vetted library?

Comment: @aglassman it's fine to roll your own API as long as you use a trusted _implmentation_. The point is that `java.security` is a little tricky to get right; and it's likely that people unfamiliar with it would use it incorrectly. Producing a tested correct usage with a simple API will help to prevent that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Thanks for the code review! :) I'm still working on the getBytes part. It's a place holder since some inputs come in as UTF-8 strings, and others as Hex. So they way I go from String to byte[] is different in each case. I haven't thought through that abstraction yet.

Comment: @aglassman: I actually am using java.security. We've had code in our repository that uses it, but it took me several days to reverse engineer how/why it worked. So I'm putting that code into a shared library with a unit test suite so that our other projects can use the simplified API. It's still backed by trusted libraries though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: If I make the `en/decrypter` generic in the secret, does that imply I should add a `decrypt` method to my Secret? It seems like your suggestion is to effectively inject the decrypter in the secret. It seems like a nice idea, just making sure I understood it correctly. If I'm not adding the `decrypt` method there, how do the generics help?

Comment: @gridDragon What is the main purpose of the `Decrypter` interface? Do you ever have collection of decrypters? How are these used? You must answer what purpose it gives in order to determine if using generics will fulfill the need or not. For instance, if you use generics on the `Secret` then you can't just treat all decrypters the same way anymore and the interface gives less generalization power.

Answer (score 1):

you could make your Decryptor generic. Something like this:

```
interface Decryptor<S extends Secret>{
    public String decrypt(S secret, Key publicKey);
}
```

That way, every implementation of `Decryptor` can define its own Secret. And that way you get rid of your casting.